# ClojureScript REPL in emacs printing out extra ^Ms and nils

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurescript, cider

I'm a **ClojureScript** newbie using **emacs**, **cider**, **cljsbuild**, and **austin** with **slimerjs** on a Windows machine. I've noted that sometimes when I type into the clojurescript repl, an extra `^M` character and `nil` are appended to the output (but the return value is not nil, as indicated by the output of the repl enclosed below).  The output before the `^M` is colored red, while the `nil` output is black. What could be causing this, and how can I fix this? (Should I be reporting this as an issue to one of the project's trackers?)

```
cljs.user> 1
1
cljs.user> true
true
cljs.user> (reduce + [1 2 3])
6
cljs.user> (list [1 2 3])
([1 2 3])
cljs.user> reduce
#<function (a,e,f){switch(arguments.length){case 2:return b.call(this,
a,e);case 3:return c.call(this,a,e,f)}throw Error("Invalid arity: "+arguments.length);}>^M
nil
cljs.user> js/document
#<[object HTMLDocument]>^M
nil
cljs.user> (def d js/document)
#<[object HTMLDocument]>^M
nil
cljs.user> (nil? d)
false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^M is windows line ending. Answer how ho hide it in Emacs can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730751/hiding-m-in-emacs).

Printing of `nil` in general is normal behaviour and it's not specific to Clojurescript or Emacs. All forms return a value (which may be `nil`) and also may produce side-effects:

```
cljs.user> (println 1) 
1 ; Side effect - printed value
nil ; Result of evaluation
```

However returning `nil` for `js/document`, `(def d js/document)` and similar "not-nil" forms is Austin specific behaviour and probably can be treated as minor bug.

Comment: Thanks! I also added `(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'remove-dos-eol)` to activate remove-dos-eol whenever I was in a REPL.